# Weird Juniper switch behavior

Tags: juniper, networking, juniper-ex

Weird Juniper switch behavior
I have bought EX4300 and SRX300 on ebay to study it and started to read documentation.

After some time i wanted to test my knowledge and configure it to test it at home.

I have managed to set up SRX300 as a router with ge-0/0/[0-3] ports configured as untagged with different subnetworks in each of them, and SRX works as a clock without any problem.

But when i wired SRX and EX, i found some unexpected behavior.

Configuration Description:

```
 SRX           subnetwork                     EX
ge-0/0/0         mgmt                        ge-0/0/0
ge-0/0/1         home                        ge-0/0/2
ge-0/0/2         pbx                         ge-0/0/4
ge-0/0/3         video                       ge-0/0/6
```

When i connected patch cord from SRX ge-0/0/1 to EX ge-0/0/2 (both interfaces configured as home subnetwork) all worked fine, but when i connected second patch cord from SRX ge-0/0/0 to EX ge-0/0/0 (both interfaces configured as mgmt subnetwork) all devices on home subnetwork stopped discovering default gateway in this subnetwork.

Same situation goes to other subnetworks, when i connect only pbx subnetwork patch cord all works fine, until i connect home subnetwork patch cord.

If i connect video and pbx subnetwork only pbx works.

If i connect all of them, only mgmt works.

All other configuration, except this 4 ports with untagged networks on each of them works fine.

I don't understand, what could cause this behavior, can someone explain it to me?

EX4300 configuration:

```
root> show configuration
## Last commit: 2019-04-16 10:40:12 EEST by root
version 20190319.203446_builder.r1013243;
groups {
    global {
        system {
            login {
                ....
            }
        }
    }
}
apply-groups global;
system {
    login {
        user root {
            ....
        }
    }
    root-authentication {
        ....
    }
    services {
        ssh {
            root-login deny;
            protocol-version v2;
            port 22;
        }
        web-management {
            http {
                interface me0.0;
            }
            https {
                system-generated-certificate;
            }
        }
    }
    auto-snapshot;
    time-zone Europe/Kiev;
    name-server {
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
        1.0.0.1;
        1.1.1.1;
    }
    syslog {
        user * {
            any emergency;
        }
        file messages {
            any notice;
            authorization info;
        }
        file interactive-commands {
            interactive-commands any;
        }
    }
    processes {
        dhcp-service {
            traceoptions {
                file dhcp_logfile size 10m;
                level all;
                flag all;
            }
        }
    }
}
interfaces {
    ge-0/0/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members mgmt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/2 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members home;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/4 {
        native-vlan-id 22;
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                interface-mode trunk;
                vlan {
                    members [ pbx home ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/6 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members video;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/8 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members guest;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/9 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members home;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/10 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching;
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/11 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members home;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/12 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members video;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/13 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members mgmt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/14 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members video;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/15 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members mgmt;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/16 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members pbx;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/17 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members pbx;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/18 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members pbx;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/19 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members pbx;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/20 {
        native-vlan-id 5;
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                interface-mode trunk;
                vlan {
                    members [ mgmt home guest ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/21 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                vlan {
                    members video;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/22 {
        native-vlan-id 5;
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                interface-mode trunk;
                vlan {
                    members [ mgmt guest home ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/0/23 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                interface-mode trunk;
                vlan {
                    members [ home pbx video guest mgmt ];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/2/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                storm-control default;
            }
        }
    }
    xe-0/2/0 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                storm-control default;
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/2/1 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                storm-control default;
            }
        }
    }
    xe-0/2/1 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                storm-control default;
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/2/2 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                storm-control default;
            }
        }
    }
    xe-0/2/2 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                storm-control default;
            }
        }
    }
    ge-0/2/3 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                storm-control default;
            }
        }
    }
    xe-0/2/3 {
        unit 0 {
            family ethernet-switching {
                storm-control default;
            }
        }
    }
    irb {
        unit 5 {
            family inet {
                address 10.5.5.43/24;
            }
        }
        unit 11 {
            family inet {
                address 10.33.11.43/24;
            }
        }
        unit 12 {
            family inet;
        }
        unit 22 {
            family inet {
                address 10.41.22.43/32;
            }
        }
        unit 23 {
            family inet;
        }
    }
    me0 {
        unit 0 {
            family inet {
                address 172.16.27.43/24;
            }
        }
    }
}
forwarding-options {
    storm-control-profiles default {
        all;
    }
    dhcp-relay {
        server-group {
            home-dhcp {
                10.33.11.1;
            }
            pbx-dhcp {
                10.41.22.1;
            }
        }
        group all {
            interface irb.11;
            interface irb.22;
        }
    }
}
protocols {
    lldp {
        interface all;
    }
    lldp-med {
        interface all;
    }
    igmp-snooping {
        vlan default;
    }
    rstp {
        interface all;
    }
}
poe {
    interface all;
}
vlans {
    home {
        vlan-id 11;
        l3-interface irb.11;
    }
    guest {
        vlan-id 12;
        l3-interface irb.12;
    }
    mgmt {
        vlan-id 5;
        l3-interface irb.5;
    }
    pbx {
        vlan-id 22;
        l3-interface irb.22;
    }
    video {
        vlan-id 23;
        l3-interface irb.23;
    }
}

{master:0}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least on the switch, RSTP is active. Likely, you've got a switch group on the SRX, and STP blocks the supposedly redundant interfaces.

Check the logs and add the sanitized SRX config if you can't figure it out.